# Android Studio 4.2 - The APK Set archive does not contain the following modules: [feature_login]

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, android-studio-4.2

After updating android studio from 4.1.3 to 4.2 and especially com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0 dependency, I receive the above error for my project that contains dynamic feature modules.

Does someone else face the same problem?

The problem is solved if editing deploy setting in Run -> Edit Configurations from **APK from app bundle** to **Default APK** or downgrade the above dependency to 4.1.3.

I have tried to invalidate caches and delete manually build folder but the problem was not solved